# Dwolla - Linked Transactions or Duel Payments

Tags: linked-list, dwolla

Scenario - Want to have a customer purchase a product on our site with the payment going directly to the vendor and at the same time trigger a payment from the vendor to us.

Can this be done with Dwolla?

Comment: Or something like PayPal adaptive Payments would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to take a percentage of the order, or just apply a fee on top of dwolla's fee? Also, what environment are you working in?  i.e. Are you coding in php, ruby, etc, or using one of the simple links that Dwolla provides for non-coders?

Edit: You can do a fixed fee or a percentage for the facilitator fee.  Here's a link to the api:
https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/pages/facilitator  You can change that programmatically per transaction if you so desire according to the documentation.

If you are using Dwolla's non-coder links then I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done using the [`transactionSend()` API call](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/transactions/send) where your Dwolla account would send money to the vendor's Dwolla account. As stated above, you can take a `facilitator fee` from this transaction (`facilitatorAmount` is one of the `transactionSend()` options).